# Setting up a web application using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to setting up a web based application. I have a server with MySQL setup with a database. The site is running my login web page. Currently I have users setup using MyPhpAdmin which will quickly prove burdensome. More importantly, once I run the command `"$connection = mysqli_connect('1.2.3.4', $username, $password, 'databasename');"`, the variable `$connection` does not continue to exist on other PHP scripts even though I set it as global and tried `"  $GLOBALS['connection'] = $connection;".`

Is there a standard practice to login with a single account for the PHP code and then manage the users with a database table? I'm a little leery of that approach for security reasons.

Comment: You should consider using separate PHP file with all your DB logic (since using GLOBALS is not a good practice), where `$connection` is  private to this file only and DB queries is retrieved from public function calls, e.g. `public getMySQLData()`. In each call you can check if connection is open by something like this: `if (mysqli_ping($connection)) { //connection is valid, your code }`.

Comment: `$GLOBALS` doesn't set variables across multiple scripts. Have you read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had looked at the documentation by applied my own assumption about GLOBAL. The first statement cleared up that misconception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the `$_GLOBALS`. once you declared a variable outside a function or a class, it is already registered globally.

```php
<?php


$foo = "bar";

function foo(){
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}

echo $_GLOBALS["foo"]; // Output: bar
foo(); // Output: bar
```

- you can read more about PHP GLOBALS [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Answer (score 0):

i recomended to you not use mysqli, is better use PDO connection like this

```
$Engine = 'mysql';
$Host = 'YOUR_HOST';
$Name = 'DB_NAME';
$User = 'YOUR_USER';
$Pass = 'YOUR_PASS';
$Charset = 'YOUR_CHARSET_DB';

$Connection = new PDO($this->Engine.':host='.$this->Host.';dbname='.$this->Name.';$this->Charset', $this->User, $this->Pass);
```

you can used like this

```
try {
    $Connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $User, $Pass);
    foreach($Connection ->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $fila) {
        print_r($fila);
    }
    $Connection = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

the PDO connection close after the query is done you dont need to close manually

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into pdo